# Problem by inserting values from Excel to DB using python

Tags: python, sql

Hey I am trying to loop throgh each row in an excel worksheet and add it to the DB.

By this code part

```
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    id, name, category = row
    sql = "INSERT INTO category (id, name, category) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)"
    cur.execute(sql, (id, name, category))
```

I get this error:

> oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

I am using these two libraries openpyxl and cx_Oracle.